# Round-robin in postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a few simple tables:

checks

```
+----+--------+
| Id |  site  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | google |
|  2 | yahoo  |
|  3 | reddit |
+----+--------+
```

locations

```
+----+-----------+
| Id | location  |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | dallas    |
|  2 | singapore |
|  3 | london    |
+----+-----------+
```

checks_locations

```
+----------+-------------+
| check_id | location_id |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 |           1 |
|        1 |           2 |
|        1 |           3 |
|        2 |           2 |
|        2 |           3 |
|        3 |           3 |
+----------+-------------+
```

checks_requests

```
+----------+-------------+
| check_id | location_id |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 |           2 |
|        2 |           3 |
+----------+-------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through the locations associated with each site every time I create a request. Essentially, I want to bring back a list of checks with the next location id, based on the last request.

In this instance, that would be:

```
google, last location 2, next location 3  
yahoo, last location 3, next location 2 
reddit, last location nil, next location 3
```

This is my attempt:

```
select c.*, r.location_id as last_location, cl.location_id
from checks c
left outer join lateral (
  select * from requests r
  where c.id = r.check_id order by id desc limit 1
) r on true 
left outer join lateral (
  select * from checks_locations cl
  where c.id = cl.check_id and r.location_id != cl.location_id
  order by cl.location_id
) cl on true;
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+
| id |  site  | last_location | location_id |
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | google | 3             | 1           |
|  1 | google | 3             | 2           |
|  2 | yahoo  | 2             | 3           |
|  3 | reddit | null          | null        |
+----+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

As you can see, I'm not really that close, and am completely lost on how I might achieve this, or whether this is even possible with PostgreSQL. I've attempted to integrate a case statement into the order by/offset etc but it's a giant mess and I can't help but think there is a better way.

Here is a DB fiddle with everything setup: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6fiK4gbkQMsV9yCm2c7qnk/3

Comment: yahoo Doesn't have location id 1.

Comment: updated. cheers

Comment: have also considered pulling in an array of location ids with the join, and storing the 'next location' in the request row itself. would greatly simplify, and then I could offload the logic to my application.

Comment: Where did "quora" come from?

Comment: eek, jumping around between different data. that's in my example (db fiddle). starting to think even if I do achieve a query that works it is going to be very slow as the request table grows. might just store location ids and location pointer in the checks table and update that as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This solution:

```
SELECT ck.id,
       ck.site,
       rq.location_id AS last_location,
       CASE WHEN (rq.location_id IS NULL OR rq.location_id = (SELECT MAX(location_id)
                                                             FROM checks_locations clk
                                                             WHERE clk.check_id = ck.id))
                THEN MIN(cl.location_id)
            ELSE
                rq.location_id + 1
            END AS next_Location        
FROM checks ck
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT check_id,
                        location_id
                        FROM requests
                        WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(Id) 
                                     FROM requests
                                     GROUP BY check_id
                                     )
                ) AS rq
ON ck.id = rq.check_id 
LEFT JOIN checks_locations cl
ON ck.id = cl.check_id
GROUP BY ck.id,
       ck.site,
       rq.location_id;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id |    site   | last_location | next_location
-----------------------------------------------
1  |    google |      3        |      1
2  |    quora  |      2        |      3
3  |    yahoo  |      null     |      3
```

Link to the demo:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=bc88ccae2638a9f78f00912b9bb95539

Comment: Good stuff! Learning a lot from that answer. I think this gets me almost the way there. It's just the ` rq.location_id + 1` that won't work if there are non-sequential ids.. such as 1, 2, 4 and current location is 2.. unless I'm missing something? Have also since had reservations about building a query with so many subqueries. The request table will grow quite large. Have decided to instead store location ids array on the checks table and a location id pointer, which I will then update in bulk after each series of requests.

Comment: @DamienRoche Thanks .... I am also not getting how to minimize the use of subqueries as well as take care of this part `rq.location_id +1`. I am still working on this if i will find answer i will surely update the answer.

Comment: No worries. I'm just happy to learn from the answer as I struggled for the last few hours to wrap my head around it. I have since decided to go a much simpler route, of which I have a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898644/postgres-bulk-update-query-to-update-pointer-for-an-array