# Postgres: Bulk update query to update pointer for an array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently have this in a table:

```
+----+--------+--------------+------------------+
| id |  site  | location_ids | current_location |
+----+--------+--------------+------------------+
|  1 | google | [1,2,3]      |                2 |
|  2 | yahoo  | [2,3]        |                3 |
|  3 | reddit | [1]          |                1 |
|  4 | stack  | [1,2,4]      |                2 |
+----+--------+--------------+------------------+
```

What I want to do is a bulk update query that will update the current location to either the next item in the array, or, if we've reached the end of the array, reset to the first item.

I am currently doing this manually and building the logic in my application:

```
update checks as chk set
  current_location = c.current_location
from (values
      (1, 3),
      (2, 2),
      (3, 1),
      (4, 4)
) as c(id, current_location)
where c.id = chk.id
```

Comment: What data type is `location_ids`?

Comment: It's an array of ints.

Comment: What version of PG are you using?

Comment: 9.6, but the version is flexible as I'm working with a fresh db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case expression the other posters have used could be replaced with `mod` function for a slightly shorter solution:

[`%`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) is the infix version of [`mod`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE)

```
UPDATE checks
SET current_location = location_ids[
      array_position(location_ids, current_location) % cardinality(location_ids) + 1
]
```

Comment: Are there any _additional_ performance implications with this?

Comment: probably minimal either way. here we call array_position, array_length & mod once each, the case based solution has a branch and calls array_length twice.

Comment: Yup. Fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: Clever, I like it!

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to write it that doesn't involve calling `array_position` twice, but if you're using PG 9.5 (for the array_position function) you could do:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET current_location = location_ids[CASE WHEN array_length(location_ids, 1) = array_position(location_ids, current_location) THEN 1 ELSE array_position(location_ids, current_location) + 1 END];
```

So it gets the index of `current_location` and checks if it's at the end of the array. If it is, it gets the value at index 1 (arrays indexes in PG are 1-based). If it's not, it gets the value at that position + 1.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming Postgres 9.5 or higher for this answer:

You can find the index of the current location ID by using `array_position(location_ids, current_location)`. The next location ID should be the one at the next index, unless that index is bigger than the length of the array. That can be put into a single expression:

```
case 
  when 
   array_position(location_ids, current_location) + 1 > cardinality(location_ids) 
     then 1 
   else array_position(location_ids, current_location) + 1 
end
```

This expression can directly be used in an update statement:

```
update checks
   set current_location = 
        location_ids[case 
                      when array_position(location_ids, current_location) + 1 > cardinality(location_ids) 
                        then 1 
                      else array_position(location_ids, current_location) + 1 
                    end];
```

Comment: Thanks! That'll do.